# Correct way to create a webservice to communicate with an iOS app

Tags: php, ios, ruby, ajax, web-services

I want to experiment with writing an app that allows the user to submit a string of text. These strings would be cataloged (let's say with an ID) and stored on a web server somewhere. Apart from being able to submit text, the user can also view other submitted texts, for example viewing the most recent submissions, and then loading more if they want to see more.

I think I could figure out the iOS portion of this, but I'm blank on the web side of things. What do I need to run on the web server (php, ruby, something else? i have only heard of these but don't know what they really are/do) to get this kind of setup to work?

(As a side note, this seems like something that a lot of apps do (twitter comes to mind) so if there are other resources that would explain this to me, I would be more than happy if someone pointed me towards them. I just want to get this right the first time).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most server-side applications use the [REST pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST) for serving up data and receiving responses. You can write a RESTful application using many languages, but Ruby and Python are probably the most popular and easiest to get started with.

You can do something simple with [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-ios-development-sinatra-cedar), a web application deployment platform for Ruby, or use an existing service like [Parse](https://parse.com/). Consuming a REST service can be done easily using [RestKit](http://restkit.org/) for iOS.

Comment: thanks! Do you think it could also be done perhaps getting the app to communicate directly with an SQL database?

Comment: You could, but you're generally better off moving that sort of logic into the server; I just updated my answer with more information on REST services which abstract the database stuff that you'd need.

Comment: @Senior is right, you better don't communicate directly with the DB, as it could lead to important security problems. Regarding Parse, I've been reading a lot about them in the last few months, and I think that if you're able to monetize your app and really don't know how to properly create and maintain a webservice or don't want the kind of problems it gives you, is the easiest way.

Comment: @Sergi good advice, but I also want to use this as an opportunity to learn about web services and how to maintain them. I think it's a useful skill I could have. That was basically the goal of my question, so I could learn more about these things

Comment: Then you better stick ;) as @Senior said with something that makes live easy for you on the sysops side, like Heroku if you go the Rails or Python way, PHPFog for PHP or even Google App Engine for Java or Python. Believe me, I've been developing for web for the last 12 years being CTO for some projects, and if you don't have a sysops guy you better simplify as much as possible the sysops part.

BTW, if you think that Senior answer is right mark it as resolved to award him the points.